# How does callback exactly work in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, callback, express

I have a mongob with user object. Here's the schema:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "50658c835b821298d3000001"
    },
    "email": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "id": 1
}
```

I wrote a simple demo (only main parts):

```
function findByEmail(email, callback) {
  db.collection("users", function(err, collection) {
      collection.find({}, function(err, users) {
          users.each(function(err, user) {
              if (user) {
                  if (user.email === email) {
                      //for a case, is we found user - return it
                      callback(null, user);
                  }
              }
          });
          //for a case, is we didn't find user - return null
          callback(null, null);
      });
  });
}
```

And a route for testing:

```
app.get('/test',function(req,res){
  findByEmail("admin", function(err, user){
    res.send(user);
  })
})
```

After lauching localhost:3000/test I get

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

If I comment line `callback(null, null);` I dont get this error. It seems that callback works... twice! How can it be? I supposed that if I `if (user.email === email) { ... }` works, and `callback(null, user);` is launched, function `findbyEmail` returns `<user>` to `app.get`, but callback works twice (for `callback(null, null);` also) even when `if (user.email === email) { ... }` is true.

Comment: Well, what would stop the `callback(null, null)` to be invoked? You're calling it right after you iterate over the `users` array, which happens unconditionally.

Comment: Another callback! callback(null, user); - if we found user, callback(null, user); is invoked, and it directs execution to app.get. It's like a return/break. Or not? o_O

Comment: No, callbacks are functions. When you call a function, well, you call a function. Your execution continues after that, just like after you, you know, call a function.

Comment: Hm, I thought about callbacks in a wrong way. So, how would you suggest me to direct execution to app.get? with 'return'? Or using 'break'?

Comment: tried to use "return callback(null, user);" and still get Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `callback(null, null)` right after you iterate over results. So if you have some results - `callback` will be called twice:

- one for handled results (which will send output)
- and second time after iteration.

You should only call `callback(null, null)` if there is no results...

```
if (!users || users.toArray().length==0) callback(null, null);
```

Comment: Your solution worked, thanks! However I really dont understand why simple return doesnt'work and gives me Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. ?

Comment: Or return also dont't routes execution to app.get and I should manually break() it?

Comment: @IlyaRusanen, well, if you add return in front of `callback` it will work, without it execution will continue, callback cannot control execution flow of callee...

Comment: Your last edit with return still gives me the same error. But if (!users || users.toArray().length==0) callback(null, null); solution works. It seems that return doesn't break a function

Comment: @IlyaRusanen, oh, I missed that first callback was one level deeper, so `return` wouldn't help much here too, sorry for miss-leading with that one...

Comment: However if (!users || users.toArray().length==0) callback(null, null); is not ideal. If not matching users are found. it simply doesn't return anything at all and program hangs...

Comment: @IlyaRusanen, well, only you what to send to back from your code, currently you sending `null` (but nothing stops you from sending something more appropriate)...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17315/discussion-between-ilya-rusanen-and-juicy-scripter)

Answer (score 0):

You callback still gets executed:

```
for ( var key in obj ) {
  foo();
}

foo();
```

Why would you expect the 2nd foo() not to be called?

You need to do return foo(); if you don't want to keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Let's refer to the function you pass to `collection.find` as `outer` and to the one you pass to `users.each` as `inner` (I have labeled them so in the code block below for clarity). Now, the problem is that when you invoke `callback(null, user)` in `inner`, the `users.each` loop continues to run, and will still proceed with testing all the remaining elements in the result; also, the `outer` function is still not finished, and will invoke your `callback(null, null)` callback after the `users.each` loop is done. You can't really just `return` after you find a user and invoke `callback(null, user)` as I previously suggested, as this will only terminate that single iteration of the `users.each` loop and will proceed with the next and all of the remaining elements; you need to define a flag indicating whether you have found the record already or not:

```
collection.find({}, function outer(err, users) {
    var found = false;
    users.each(function inner(err, user) {
        if (user && !found) {
            if (user.email === email) {
                //for a case, is we found user - return it
                callback(null, user);
                found = true;
            }
        }
    });
    //for a case, is we didn't find user - return null
    if (!found) {
        callback(null, null);
    }
});
```

Also note that you can do that search for a user record by email *entirely* in mongo and replace your whole logic with this:

```
collection.find({ email: email }, function(err, users) {
    callback(null, users.length? users[0]: null);
});
```